# Redirect to angular ui route from nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router, response.redirect

I want to access angulars ui route from nodejs directly for which 
I have setup in ui router with following state

app.js

```
.state('video', {
    url: '/video/:patientId',
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/patient/views/video.html'              
})
```

And i am tryig to access it directly from node controller

app.controller.js

```
var token = '';
 router.use('/', function (req, res, next) 
 {   
    if(req.query.token!==undefined && req.session.token==undefined){
       var returnUrl = '/app/#/video/'+req.query.token;
       token=req.query.token;
       return res.redirect(returnUrl);              
    }

    if(req.session.token==undefined && token ==''){
      return res.redirect('/index.html');   
    }    
    next();
});

// serve angular app files from the '/app' route
router.use('/', express.static('app'));
```

But i am not able to access it, gets redirected to "/app" two times and loads index.html

in server i have following configuration,

```
      // routes
       app.use('/login', require('./controllers/login.controller'));
       app.use('/app', require('./controllers/app.controller'));

     // make '/app' default route
       app.get('/', function (req, res) {
                return res.redirect('/app');
       });
```

In above configuration if i hit with url

"http://localhost:8181/app/#/video/rserser" i get redirected like this

"http://localhost:8181/index.html/video/rserser"

but wanna access ui route directly on this url
"http://localhost:8181/app/#/video/rserser".

I am unable to access it directly so tried to access by above configuration using below url 
"http://localhost:8181/app/video?token=test"
upon which i did got redirected to desired state,
but if i hit url

"http://localhost:8181"

it is not redirectig to index.html but redirects to angulars default route, as i am unable to reset the var token in node controller after getting redirected to angulars route.

Comment: redirect will not work with xhr  requests you need to send only data from the server and handle all the rendering and routes on the front

Comment: Its not xhr request its a url which i want to get redirected to there is no xhr request being made.
want to get redirected here "/app/#/video/test" .

Comment: anguler is spa framework , it useses xhr for all its server side requests

Comment: It is very strange that you want to do 302 redirects for HTML5 mode URLs. Is this an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? Are you having some other problem that you are trying to solve with this strangeness? Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - HTML link rewriting](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html-link-rewriting).

Comment: No it's not XY-problem I just want to access angular ui state from nodejs on request from browser.